# Why do we keep a testing set when doing research?

Tags: machine-learning

I am really curious about this. From my exploring of research in Machine Learning, I've seen that the same test set is used from paper to paper. While i can understand keeping the same set for different approaches so as to make results comparable, doesn't it make it so that the approaches are eventually getting more and more optimized to the test sets, rather than applicable to numerous problems?

Answer (score 1):

What you say is true: each paper is climbing the gradient of the well-worn test dataset, and may simply be overfitting that example. Balancing this out, it can be hard to gather a good dataset and release it publicly.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, that is actually true. For this reason, new test sets should be introduced on a regular basis. Also, people are actually following this practice. For example if you look at natural language processing (which is my application area), similar shared tasks are repeated each year but with different data sets (for example at SemEval). But it might still be that test sets should be renewed more often. Also, I think it's less bad if the data set you are using is representative.

Comment: See [confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias). In a nutshell, the first nut case theory that sticks to a neural network has a persistence that outlives its proven utility, such that for a neural network to improve, some pruning of unused connections is needed.